# Railsのパラメータについて教えてください

Tags: ruby-on-rails

blogにコメントをつけるアプリを作成中のRails初心者です。
パラメータのことで教えてください。

views

```
<%= link_to '削除', blog_comment_path(blog, comment), method: :delete %>
```

ここでbinding.pryでcommentの中身を見ると、

```
 id: 2,
 blog_id: 1,
 content: "コメントです",
 created_at: Fri, 04 May 2018 21:08:30 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Fri, 04 May 2018 21:08:30 UTC +00:00
```

と、それぞれの値がきちんと確認できるのですが、
comment_controllerに渡されるパラメータを見ると

```
{"controller"=>"comments", "action"=>"destroy", "blog_id"=>"1", "id"=>"2"}
```

というもので、idしか渡されていません。

なぜこうなるのかがわかりません。
ルーティングは以下の通りです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

基本的なことで恐縮ですが、ご教示宜しくお願い致します。

環境：
ruby:2.3.1
rails:5.1.6

Comment: `id` の他に `blog_id` も渡されているようですが、それ以外に何が渡されることを期待していますか?

Comment: masmさん、ありがとうございます！
私としては、commentsテーブルのカラムであるcontentも渡されるはずだと考えております。説明が不足しており申し訳ありませんでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`blog_comment_path` は path を返してくれるだけです。
そして、path はスクリーンショットにあるように、`/blogs/:blog_id/comments/:id(.:format)` です。

id があれば削除はできますし、もしその他の情報が必要な場合でも DB から取得すれば良いです。

```
comment = Comment.find(params[:id])    # DB から取得
Rails.logger.debug(comment.content)    # 使用
comment.destroy                        # 削除
```

Comment: masmさん、ありがとうございました！そのような理屈なのですね。とても勉強になりました！感謝感謝です！